# Magento2 DataDump

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, magento, magento2

How to get Data Dump from magento cloud. I have tried magento-cloud db:dump. It has given me .sql file. I dont know where to run that file.

I tried Magento CLI. I got sql file using magento-cloud db:dump in my terminal.

P.S. I am using Mac

Comment: How is sql server relevant?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need sales_items.csv. I can not directly export from magento backend as it only  exports sales.csv( this file does not contain items associated with each order).

Thats all I need.